# Find the complete graph as sugraph using maple

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, graph-theory, maple, planar-graphs

Given a connected connected graph G which is non planar how to use maple to find it contain K_5 complete graph on 5 vertices in it as subgraph using maple

Comment: Found answer we can do it by using the maximum clique function

Comment: Hi Sriram. You should type up your solution as an answer here, so others can learn from it.